# Click Once applications not launching in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, clickonce

I have a web application which supports two click once applications. The web application works well under IE11 and both click once application launch under IE11. However I was recently trying to get my web application to operate under Chrome version 65. I installed the following ClickOnce extension under Chrome:

Meta4 ClickOnce Launcher

Now the above extension would not launch the supporting Click Once application in Chrome. The Click Once applications were developed in VS 2010.

I use php to call the Click Once application

```
header( 'Location: http://sanplic02.corp.mycompany.com/LaunchCatia/LaunchCatiaPWBSTART.application?licence=DP2&computername='.DisplayComputerName());
```

Does anybody have any ideas as to why this is so.

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Now I eventually got my web application to work in Chrome. All of the above is correct. The extension I used was the Meta4 Click Once Launcher. The line of php code above is also correct this is how I launch the click once application supported by the web application.

So what was the underlying problem. Well essentially I was disabling my submit buttons in code. Even though the submit buttons were programmatically disabled they operated correctly under IE11 another words the submit buttons appeared enabled in IE11. However in chrome on the other hand they were disabled, hence Chrome would not execute the script that launched the click once application script. So once I removed the code to disable the submit button all went well.

The joys of cross browser compatibility.